# How to create a function with fixed single argument that ignores callback arguments

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, lodash

I have this piece of code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState(null);
  return (
    <>
      <AppHeader onSearchClick={() => setSelectedMovie(null)} />
      <AppBody selectedMovie={selectedMovie} onMovieSelect={setSelectedMovie} />
      <AppFooter />
    </>
  );
};
```

Recently I'm refactoring to `FP` style. To make it look nice I would like to avoid calling `setSelectedMovie(null)` in `onSearchClick` lambda.

What I would like to achieve is to pass a function that will ignore `onSearchClick` arguments and will be called with fixed `null`, something like this:

```
<AppHeader onSearchClick={setSelectedMovieCalledWithNullOnly} />
```

Is it possible, e.g. with `lodash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.wrap()` to supply a constant value to the function:

```js
const fn = x => console.log(x)
const alwaysNull = _.wrap(null, fn)

fn(5) // 5
alwaysNull(1243281) // null
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

If there might be other params, and you to limit the function, you can also use `_.ary()` to set the arity of the function (the number of parameters the function accepts) to `0`:

```js
const fn = (...args) => console.log(args)
const alwaysNull = _.ary(_.wrap(null, fn), 0)

fn(5) // 5
alwaysNull(1, 2) // null
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And in your case:

```
const App = () => {
  const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState(null);

  const setSelectedMovieCalledWithNullOnly = _.wrap(setSelectedMovie, null);

  return (
    <>
      <AppHeader onSearchClick={setSelectedMovieCalledWithNullOnly)} />
      <AppBody selectedMovie={selectedMovie} onMovieSelect={setSelectedMovie} />
      <AppFooter />
    </>
  );
};
```